# Entity Framework "SELECT IN" not using parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

Why is Entity Framework putting literal values in generated SQL rather than using parameters when using a "SELECT IN":

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    var values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var query = context.Things.Where(x => values.Contains(x.Id));

    Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
}
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[PaymentConfigurations] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (1, 2, 3)
```

I see a lot of cached query plans in SQL Server. Is there anyway of making EF to put parameters rather than harcoded values, or activating parameter sniffing is the only option?

It happens also in EF Core.

Comment: At the engine level `IN` clauses cannot be parameterized.

Comment: Why exactly do you wish to parameterise the generated SQL? Surely the usual reasons don't apply when you're using the ORM as intended?

Comment: @andrensairr to avoid having a cached query plan for every combination of values in the in. There is always less than 10 parameters, so I would expect around 10 query plans cached, one per amount of parameters... rather the actual 1500+ that I can see in the activity monitor.

Comment: `At the engine level IN clauses cannot be parameterized.` What engine is that referring to @AlexK.? _SQL Server definitely allows parameters to be used in IN clauses._

Comment: Consider using the "optimize for ad hoc workloads" Server Configuration Option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL did this. I think it was abandoned because of the max number of parameters allowed in one query (2100).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't say *why* EF (Core) designers decided to use constants instead of variables when translating `Enumerable.Contains`. As @Gert Arnold pointed out in the comments, could be related to SQL query parameter count limit.

Interestingly, both EF (6.2) and EF Core (2.1.2) generate `IN` with parameters when you use the equivalent `||` expression like:

```
var values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var value0 = values[0];
var value1 = values[1];
var value2 = values[2]; 
var query = context.Things.Where(x =>
    x.Id == value0 ||
    x.Id == value1 ||
    x.Id == value2);
```

EF6.2 generated query is

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Things] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (@p__linq__0,@p__linq__1,@p__linq__2)
```

EF Core 2.1 does something similar.

So the solution is to convert the `Contains` expression to `||` based expression. It has to be dynamically using `Expression` class methods. And to make it easier to use, could be encapsulated in a custom extension method, which internally user `ExpressionVisitor` to perform the conversion.

Something like this:

```
public static partial class EfQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Parameterize<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var expression = new ContainsConverter().Visit(source.Expression);
        if (expression == source) return source;
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    class ContainsConverter : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Enumerable) &&
                node.Method.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains) &&
                node.Arguments.Count == 2 &&
                CanEvaluate(node.Arguments[0]))
            {
                var values = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable>>(node.Arguments[0]).Compile().Invoke();
                var left = Visit(node.Arguments[1]);
                Expression result = null;
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    // var variable = new Tuple<TValue>(value);
                    var variable = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Tuple<>).MakeGenericType(left.Type), value);
                    // var right = variable.Item1;
                    var right = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(variable), nameof(Tuple<int>.Item1));
                    var match = Expression.Equal(left, right);
                    result = result != null ? Expression.OrElse(result, match) : match;
                }
                return result ?? Expression.Constant(false);
            }
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }

        static bool CanEvaluate(Expression e)
        {
            if (e == null) return true;
            if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
                return CanEvaluate(((UnaryExpression)e).Operand);
            if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
                return CanEvaluate(((MemberExpression)e).Expression);
            return e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant;
        }
    }
}
```

Applying it to the sample query

```
var values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var query = context.Things
    .Where(x => values.Contains(x.Id))
    .Parameterize();
```

produces the desired translation.

Comment: Brilliant (again)! Note that another `||` condition on _another_ property can turn the generation of `IN` into a regular chain of `OR` predicates. But anyway, it's still parametrized.

Comment: sorry, I get this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[EntityModel.tblParamNameProduct] Parameterize[tblParamNameProduct](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[EntityModel.tblParamNameProduct])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. Probably because I need to continue with another .Select() after .Parameterize(). When I insert .ToArray() between .Parameterize() and another .Select() it works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Whats nice: the query is paremeterized IN(@p__linq__0,@p__linq__1,...) clause.

Comment: @orhor The problem is not the additional LINQ operators after `Parameterize()` call, but the call itself being a part of another query expression tree, in which case it is not called at all, but just memorized and then of course translator is reporting it as unknown method. It really has to be applied to top level query root, otherwise it won't work. The simplest is to call it on the final query - it doesn't require `DbSet`, works on any queryable, including the ones with custom projection (`Select`) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterised queries with `IN` can be done, though it's a little round-about. You will need to use a direct SQL query, and generate the parameterised SQL manually, something like the following:

```
var values = new object[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var idx = 0;
var query = context.Things.SqlQuery($@"
    SELECT
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[PaymentConfigurations] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN ({string.Join(",", values.Select(i => $"@p{idx++}"))})",
    values);
```

The generated list of parameter names are directly embedded into the SQL used in the query, and are provided values by the `values` parameter. Note that you may need to ensure that your `values` array is an `object[]` and not `int[]` to ensure it's unpacked into the SqlQuery params. This approach is not so easy to maintain as a LINQ query, however sometimes we have to make these compromises for the sake of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at LINQKit https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit

Then your code would look like this:

```csharp
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    var values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Thing>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
       predicate = predicate.Or(thing => thing.Id == value);
    }

    var query = context.Things.Where(predicate);

    Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
}
```

Your SQL will look something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[PaymentConfigurations] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @__id_0 OR [Extent1].[Id] = @__id_1 OR [Extent1].[Id] = @__id_2
```

Even though it's not using `WHERE IN`, it uses the same execution plan (tested in SQL Server 2019).