# EF Core 8 - translate queries into embedded collections (OPENJSON) using expression

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression, open-json, ef-core-8.0

Here is an example of EF Core 8 translating LINQ to embedded collections:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#translate-queries-into-embedded-collections

And it works just fine:

```cs
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Address { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```cs
DbSet<Person> db;

var searchTerms = new[] { "Search #1", "Search #2", "Search #3"};

var linqQuery = db.Where(a => searchTerms.Contains(a.Address)).ToQueryString();

// DECLARE @__searchTerms_0 nvarchar(4000) = N'["Search #1","Search #2","Search #3"]';

// SELECT
//    [a].[Name], [a].[Address]
// FROM
//    [PERSON] AS[a]
// WHERE
//    [a].[Address] IN(
//    SELECT [s].[value]
//    FROM OPENJSON(@__searchTerms_0) WITH([value] varchar(8000) '$') AS[s]
// )
```

But I can't achieve the same result using an expression.

Here is what I try and expect to get `OPENJSON`:

```cs
DbSet<Person> db;

var searchTerms = new[] { "Search #1", "Search #2", "Search #3"};

var propInfo = typeof(Person).GetProperty(nameof(Person.Address))!;
var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "a");

var method = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods()
    .First(n => n.Name == "Contains" && n.GetParameters().Length == 2);

var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

var containsExp = Expression.Call(
   genericMethod, 
   Expression.Constant(searchTerms, typeof(IEnumerable<string>)), 
   Expression.Property(parameterExp, propInfo));

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(containsExp, parameterExp);

var expressionQuery = db.Where(predicate).ToQueryString();

// SELECT
//    SELECT[a].[Name], [a].[Address]
// FROM
//    [PERSON] AS[a]
// WHERE
//    [a].[Address] IN(
//        'Search #1',
//        'Search #2',
//        'Search #3'
//    )
```

Comment: `Enumerable<string>.Contains` is already translated into "in (...)" have you tried with a complex type?

Comment: I don't need anything but string[]. It is translated, but not in 
IN(
    SELECT [s].[value]
    FROM OPENJSON(@__searchTerms_0) WITH([value] varchar(8000) '$') AS[s]
 )

Comment: `a => searchTerms.Contains(a.Address)` already is an expression. You get a different query because the expression you tried to create operator-by-operator doesn't match the initial one. Why are you doing this in the first place though? That `why` matters. LINQ is already generic and dynamically composable. You can write `if (addressTerms.Length>-) { query=query.Where(a => searchTerms.Contains(a.Address));}`. Are you trying to apply dynamic UI filters to your query? In that case you probably need to use `LinqKit`.

Comment: Yes, I get an XML filter file with field names, operations and values, which I need to apply when query DB. That's why I'm forced to use Expressions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework "SELECT IN" not using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055583/entity-framework-select-in-not-using-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in first variant you have used closure over `searchTerms` array - it is what C# compiler do, and in second variant you have used `searchTerms` array directly in expression tree as constant.

For constants EF Core just decided to generate static query with `IN`, because LINQ Translator makes decision that such query will be never changed.

We can mimic such case by defining fake holder class:

```cs
class ClosureHolder
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
DbSet<Person> db;

var searchTerms = new[] { "Search #1", "Search #2", "Search #3"};

var propInfo = typeof(Person).GetProperty(nameof(Person.Address))!;
var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "a");

var method = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods()
    .First(n => n.Name == "Contains" && n.GetParameters().Length == 2);

var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

// instead of generating just constant, we generate MemberExpression to constant
var holderExpr = Expression.Constant(new ClosureHolder { Value = searchTerms });
var searchTermsExpr = Expression.Property(holderExpr, nameof(ClosureHolder.Value));

var containsExp = Expression.Call(
   genericMethod, 
   searchTermsExpr, 
   Expression.Property(parameterExp, propInfo));

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(containsExp, parameterExp);

var expressionQuery = db.Where(predicate).ToQueryString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just change the Value to be property instead of field

Comment: Nice trick, but just wondering: would it be possible to mimic the compiler's ability to create a `FieldExpression` from `searchTerms` directly? (That's what it does when compiling `a => searchTerms.Contains(a.Address)`, but it's a field in a compiler-generated class).

Comment: @GertArnold, actually we mimic compiler's behavior almost in the same way. If we specify `ClosureHolder<T>`  as generic, it will be replacement of compiler generated generic anonymous class.  EF Core treats as parameters `MemberExpression` from `ConstantExpression`. Or maybe I do not understand your comment correctly :)

Comment: Understood correctly :) I think it's the best that can be done here, it would be a bit too much to emit a new class just to get a field.

Comment: It is what compiler do also. It instantiates closure class instance and puts into constant expression. No miracle and possible optimizations. What EF Core should do from their side - DO NOT cache this closure, otherwise memory will start grow.