# How to generate IQueryable<T> that could be used by EF Core 6 to produce a parameterized query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I implemented an extension method `ApplyFilter` like this:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, FilterNode filter)
{
    if (filter == null)
        return query;

    // Create a parameter expression for the queryable entity
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "entity");

    List<FilterNode> filters = new List<FilterNode>() { filter };

    // Build the predicate expression
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = BuildPredicate<T>(filters, parameter);

    // Apply the predicate to the query
    return query.Where(predicate);
}

private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(List<FilterNode> filters, ParameterExpression parameter)
{
    Expression combinedExpression = null;

    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        Expression filterExpression;

        if (filter is FilterCriteriaNode criteriaNode)
        {
            filterExpression = BuildCriteriaExpression(criteriaNode, parameter);
        }
        else if (filter is FilterGroupNode groupNode)
        {
            filterExpression = BuildGroupExpression<T>(groupNode, parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown filter node type: {filter.GetType().Name}");
        }

        if (filterExpression != null)
        {
            combinedExpression = combinedExpression == null
                ? filterExpression
                : (filter.Operator == LogicalOperator.Or
                    ? Expression.OrElse(combinedExpression, filterExpression)
                    : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpression, filterExpression));
        }
    }

    return combinedExpression == null ? null : Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(combinedExpression, parameter);
}

private static Expression BuildCriteriaExpression(FilterCriteriaNode criteriaNode, ParameterExpression parameter)
{
    string[] propertyNames = criteriaNode.FieldName.Split('.');
    Expression propertyAccess = parameter;

    foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
    {
        propertyAccess = Expression.Property(propertyAccess, propertyName);
    }

    Expression propertyExpression = propertyAccess;
    Type propertyType = propertyExpression.Type;

    // If the property is nullable, handle the null checks
    if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        propertyExpression = Expression.Property(propertyExpression, "Value");
        propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
    }

    // Convert the constant value to the appropriate type
    Expression constant;
    if (criteriaNode.Operator == ComparisonOperator.Any || criteriaNode.Operator == ComparisonOperator.Between)
    {
        // Split the string value by comma and convert each part to the appropriate type
        string[] parts = criteriaNode.Value.Split(',');
        var constantValues = parts.Select(part => string.IsNullOrEmpty(part) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(part.Trim(), propertyType)).ToArray();

        if (criteriaNode.Operator == ComparisonOperator.Between)
        {
            // For "Between" operator, constantValues is an array with two elements
            var min = Expression.Constant(constantValues[0], propertyType);
            var max = Expression.Constant(constantValues[1], propertyType);
            return Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, min),
                Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, max)
            );
        }
        else // For "Any" operator
        {
            // Get the underlying type of the property
            Type propertyUnderlyingType = propertyType;
            if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                propertyUnderlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
            }

            // Convert constantValue to IEnumerable<T>
            var convertedValue = ((IEnumerable)constantValues).Cast<object>().Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, propertyUnderlyingType)).ToArray();

            // Create array initializer expression
            var arrayInitializer = convertedValue.Select(x => Expression.Constant(x, propertyUnderlyingType));

            // Create array expression using array initializer
            var arrayExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(propertyUnderlyingType, arrayInitializer);

            // Call the Contains method
            var containsMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                .First(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(propertyUnderlyingType);

            return Expression.Call(null, containsMethod, arrayExpression, propertyExpression);
        }
    }
    else // For other operators
    {
        // Handle null values for Equal and NotEqual operators
        if (criteriaNode.Value == null)
        {
            if (criteriaNode.Operator == ComparisonOperator.Equal)
            {
                return Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(null, propertyType));
            }
            else if (criteriaNode.Operator == ComparisonOperator.NotEqual)
            {
                if (propertyType.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) != null)
                {
                    // Property type is nullable
                    return Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(null, propertyType));
                }
                else if (propertyType.IsValueType)
                {
                    // Property type is a non-nullable value type
                    // We can't directly compare it with null
                    // You may decide what behavior to implement here
                    // For example, throwing an exception or returning a constant false expression
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot compare non-nullable value type {propertyType} with null.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Property type is a reference type
                    return Expression.NotEqual(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Comparison operator {criteriaNode.Operator} is not supported with null value.");
            }
        }
        else // For non-null values
        {
            var constantValue = Convert.ChangeType(criteriaNode.Value, propertyType);
            constant = Expression.Constant(constantValue);
        }

        // Build the appropriate comparison expression based on the operator
        switch (criteriaNode.Operator)
        {
            case ComparisonOperator.Equal:
                return Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, constant);
            case ComparisonOperator.NotEqual:
                return Expression.NotEqual(propertyExpression, constant);
            case ComparisonOperator.Contains:
                // Assuming the property is of type string, you can call the Contains method
                return Expression.Call(propertyExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }), constant);
            case ComparisonOperator.StartWith:
                return Expression.Call(propertyExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) }), constant);
            case ComparisonOperator.GreaterThan:
                return Expression.GreaterThan(propertyExpression, constant);
            case ComparisonOperator.LessThan:
                return Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression, constant);
            case ComparisonOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, constant);
            case ComparisonOperator.LessThanOrEqual:
                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, constant);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Comparison operator {criteriaNode.Operator} is not supported.");
        }
    }
}

private static Expression BuildGroupExpression<T>(FilterGroupNode groupNode, ParameterExpression parameter)
{
    if (groupNode.Children == null || !groupNode.Children.Any())
        throw new ArgumentException("Filter group must have child nodes.");

    Expression combinedExpression = null;

    foreach (var childFilter in groupNode.Children)
    {
        Expression childExpression;

        if (childFilter is FilterCriteriaNode || childFilter is FilterGroupNode)
        {
            childExpression = BuildPredicate<T>(new List<FilterNode> { childFilter }, parameter).Body;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown filter node type: {childFilter.GetType().Name}");
        }

        combinedExpression = combinedExpression == null
            ? childExpression
            : (groupNode.Operator == LogicalOperator.Or
                ? Expression.OrElse(combinedExpression, childExpression)
                : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpression, childExpression));
    }

    return combinedExpression;
}
```

When I am calling this method, it didn't generate a parameterized SQL query:

```cs
FAMSContext ctx = new FAMSContext();

var query = ctx
    .ActiveAssets(null)
    .ApplyFilter(new FilterCriteriaNode { FieldName = "Model.BrandId", Operator = ComparisonOperator.Equal, Value = "2618" })
    .SelectBasicAssetModel();

string sql = query.ToQueryString();
```

This is the generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT [a].[AssetId], [a].[AssetCode], [a].[SerialNumber], [a].[LocationId], [m].[ModelName], [m].[Description] AS [ModelDescription], [b].[BrandName], [a0].[AssetTypeName], [c].[CategoryName]
FROM [Asset] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [Model] AS [m] ON [a].[ModelId] = [m].[ModelId]
INNER JOIN [Brand] AS [b] ON [m].[BrandId] = [b].[BrandId]
INNER JOIN [AssetType] AS [a0] ON [m].[AssetTypeId] = [a0].[AssetTypeId]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [c] ON [m].[CategoryId] = [c].[CategoryId]
WHERE [m].[BrandId] = 2618
```

What should I do to make the EF Core could generate a parameterized SQL query from the returned `IQueryable` to avoid the SQL injection risk.

I tried many things to achieve this, but without success so far

Comment: There is no risk of SQL Injections. EF Core wraps literals accuratelly. For paramterizing let me check for duplicate question.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77978638/ef-core-8-translate-queries-into-embedded-collections-openjson-using-express/77983853#77983853). You should use Constant Expression tor any class instance and MemberExpressio to it's property. Then EF Core will generate parameters.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The concern isn't SQL injection, when you have literals instead of parameters then the query needs to be recompiled each time you have different values instead of being able to effectively cache the compiled query.  For frequently used queries that's often a very big deal.

Comment: @Servy, I know about recompilation, just trying to demistify SQL Injection risk.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Sorry, didn't notice that the OP thought there was an injection risk on the first read.